# Read a text file with PHP and return it to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to get the content of a txt file in JavaScript, so I want to call a php file to open and save the content of the text file into a variable and return it to JS is that possible?
I've sent variables from js to php with `$.post()` and I tried to use `$.get("php file")` but I can't return the file content can anybody help me?

Comment: Do you want to read a file (php) from the server and use its contents inside javascript?

Comment: If you want to read from a text file and then return it to javascript, then why don't you simply read the text file from javascript? One way is you can use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

Answer (score 0):

To read/get a file from the server and use it contents in javascript/jquery, you can use the shorthand-method `$.get`. Inside the callback-function, you are able to process the data returned from the server.

```
$.get("file.php", function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```